# VBA copy lines between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, copy

i'm looking for ideas how to-do my side task in exel.
Situation:
Have two workbooks- A and B. 
I need copy the specific data from A to B.
Some data is static - with case is ok, i used this code for copying it -

```
Sub Button399_Click()
    Dim sutartis As String
    Dim projektoID As String
    Dim projektas As String
    Dim Aktas As Workbook

    Worksheets("Aktas").Select
    sutartis = Range("K4")
    projektoID = Range("K5")
    projektas = Range("E12")
    Set myData = Workbooks.Open("*****")
    Worksheets("Archyve").Select
    Worksheets("Archyve").Range("A1").Select
    RowCount = Worksheets("Archyve").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    With Worksheets("Archyve").Range("A1")
        .Offset(RowCount, 0) = sutartis
        .Offset(RowCount, 1) = projektoID
        .Offset(RowCount, 2) = projektas
    End With

    myData.Save
End Sub
```

Second, i need copy data from each line and add to B workbook with static in every line.
[check the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BftKX.png)

In result, it should look like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHaxV.png)

Waiting for all suggestions and ideas!

Best regards

Comment: There are a few things that can cause an issue in your code. Can you be more specific about what the issue is with your code and which line causes the problem?

Comment: @Zac, with this code I posted, everything is good - in other workbook variables "sutartis, projektiID, projektas" successfully copying.
Now I need add code fragment to copy data from "check the list" and paste to next my variables.
I just couldn't find a solution how copy.

Answer (score 0):

The following function retrieves data from a closed workbook. **Credit** http://erlandsendata.no/?p=2106

```
Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
    Dim arg As String
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = vbNullString
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    If Dir(wbPath & wbName) = vbNullString Then Exit Function
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    'On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```